# Radio Button Circle Not Rendering - Possibly Due to Context

Tags: java, android, xml

I create programmatic radio buttons based on data in Firebase. The number of radio buttons could be anywhere from 2 - 4:

```
    public void addRadioButtonsWithFirebaseAnswers(List<DocumentSnapshot> answers) {
    mPollAnswerArrayList = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    int indexCreated = 0;
    for (DocumentSnapshot answerSnapshot : answers) {
        Answer answer = answerSnapshot.toObject(Answer.class);
        mPollAnswerArrayList.add((indexCreated), new RadioButton((getContext())));
        RadioButton radioButton = mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated);
        radioButton.setTag(indexCreated);
        radioButton.setText(answer.getAnswer().toString());
        radioButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        //TODO: Investigate if this line is necessary
        radioButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_button_answer_text_size));

        //TODO: Determne which type of RadioButton to use for consistency
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        //                radioButton.setButtonTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        } else {
            //TODO: Is this necessary? What happens?
        //                radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.black_ring);
        }

        mPollQuestionRadioGroup.addView(radioButton, mParams);
        indexCreated++;
    }
}
```

I am noticing that on API 23, for some reason these buttons are not appearing. I can still click and achieve the desired result, however the button is not actually button is not being rendered by the UI:

[image]

[image]

EDIT: It may have to do with my Context parameter, not sure if it is related to the API but instead I am not passing the context correctly. Note that the code is within a Fragment. I noticed the difference when I changed from .getContext() to .getApplicationContext(). Also possible I am not using support library radio buttons?

```
mPollAnswerArrayList.add((indexCreated), new RadioButton((getContext())));
```

Comment: you should be adding your buttons to radio group instead of adding it them to list.

Answer (score 0):

this is easiest way. Try this.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10); // leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, buttomMargin
     RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getContext());
     RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
     radioButton.setLayoutParams(params1);
     radioButton.setId(1);
     radioButton.setText("text");
     radioButton.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5); // leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, buttomMargin
     radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
```

use this for check/select the radio button,

```
radioGroup.check(3);
```

use this for unchecked the radio button,

```
radioGroup.clearCheck();
```